# gcc will auto adjust structure size

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Hi I have a defined structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short Limit;
    unsigned long Offset;
} DT_Info;
```

However, the actual size of this is 16 byte instead of 10 byte. The "Offset" will start at [DT_Info + 8].

Is there a way that I can make the compiler adjust the "Offset" start at [DT_Info + 2]?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is padding for alignment. If you're sure that your target architecture doesn't need it, you can disable it by adding `__attribute__((__packed__))` to the declaration.

Comment: Where do I add it, before the declaration of structure?? Or the function that uses the structure

Comment: Either between `struct` and `{`, or between `}` and `;`.

Comment: While on architectures like pentium, unaligned data will only lead to a slight performance loss, be careful that using unaligned  data will break your code on most other architectures. You must *really* know what you do when using `__attribute__((__packed__))`. You should always let the compiler choose and use `sizeof()` to get structure size.